# Escape '_' in MySql Like using backslash or escape statement

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Can someone please explain what is difference between using a backslash and the escape statement to escape an underscore (_) ?

Why is the result different for below queries here?

```
select 'a_a' like 'a\_a';

1

select 'a_a' like 'a_a' escape '_';

0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select 'a_a' like 'a_a' escape '_';`

In this code the `'_'` is escaping char which escapes the next char `'a'`.

> ```
> select 'a_a' like 'a\_a',
>        'a_a' like 'a_a' escape '_',
>        'a_a' like 'a__a' escape '_';
> ```
>
> ```
> 'a_a' like 'a\_a' | 'a_a' like 'a_a' escape '_' | 'a_a' like 'a__a' escape '_'
> ----------------: | --------------------------: | ---------------------------:
>                 1 |                           0 |                            1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7bb242cc8249f3b8bba280ff7dd9d90f)*